# Best practice to secure an Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron application packaged into an asar file. However, it's mentioned almost everywhere that there's no security at all for that format. Everyone can unpack it with `npx asar extract app.asar destfolder` and access the source code + resources files (certificates, images, audio, everything).

Which means technically a person can tamper with the code and resources files as much as they want and create fake builds with unwanted code.

So what are the best practices to check your application isn't tampered with? Also, where do you think i should store the private key and the public certificate (i need them to connect to my nodejs server).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is code signing. For the definition of code signing, check the Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing). For the documentation of the code signing in Electron, check this link https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/code-signing.

Second, for the additional question, what is the purpose of the private key, and the public certificate of who? And why are you need those things to connect the nodejs server?

If you want to protect the communication channel between the application and the server, use HTTPS.

Comment: Oh, so does that mean that if i tamper with an asar file for a signed application, it will prevent the user from using it for macOS/Windows? For the certificates, i need them client side to connect to my TCP server using HTTPS (nodejs.org/api/tls.html), cause of the requestCert parameter. I don't know if i should put it true or false, if yes i have to know where to store the certificates client side, right? Thanks for the help. @rymuff

Comment: @Xelik, The warning message will be pop-up when you trying to execute the tampered application. In typical TLS, you don't need a client certificate, that is an optional parameter. Also, if you want to verify or authorize the client, use JWT, SSO, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can protect it by native module.

Read [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5352143/Protecting-Electron-Based-Applications-by-Using-a) for an example.